# Issues with CompositeCollider2D and CapsuleCollider2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with interection of CompositeCollider2D and CapsuleCollider2D. My character have a capsule collider and when he stands on tilemap with composite collider he moves along the x axis very slow. When I delete composite collider and leave only tilemap collider, everything works well, but charater starts to stuck between the tiles. So, does composite collider work bad with capsulle collider or is there another problem? Same problem with the box collider

Comment: have you checked the friction values on the composite collider physics? could be slowing down movement on X axis